# Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) and Key-Value Observing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key-value-observing, automatic-ref-counting, nsnotificationcenter

I'm writing an Objective-C application using ARC and it's definitely a great improvement even though I never really minded retain counts. However, there's one case I couldn't find in the documentation on first glance.

If, in my `init` method, I call `[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:…]` to get notifications of when an ivar declared using an `@property` directive, do I need to explicitly call `removeObserver…` in the `dealloc` method, or does ARC handle key value observer cleanup? Similarly if I add my object to a `NSNotificationCenter`, does that need to be explicitly removed in `dealloc`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `removeObserver`, ARC only automates retain counts.  `removeObserver` does not impact the retain count

Comment: Thanks! That's what I initially thought but I wasn't sure.